# How to configure non-SSL POP3 mail transport in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to connect to a mail server with as little security as possible. I use this mail server for testing on my local machine. I'd like to configure my WSO2 ESB instance so that it parses incomming mail messages in a correct manner. I don't want to buy or create SSL certificates at this point.

When I create a proxy service with mailto transport I see that it comes to no connection, because my ESB talks SSL and my mail server talks plaintext. In wso2-esb-errors.log I find this error

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

I've tried different ways to switch my proxy into a plaintext mode with parameters listed here:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/MailTo+Transport

https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html

**I can't figure out how to disable the SSL-layer. So, please help!**

Current proxy configuration is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="mail_local_monitor"
   transports="mailto"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.ssl.enable">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.host">127.0.0.1</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.starttls.enable">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.password">12345</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.transport.protocol">pop3</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.user">esb@mail.local</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.port">110</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Address">esb@mail.local</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Protocol">pop3</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Full error output:

```
2014-10-09 17:24:16,971 [-] [mailto-Worker-6] ERROR MailTransportListener Error connecting to mail server for address : esb@mail.local :: Connect failed
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:148)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.checkMail(MailTransportListener.java:115)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.poll(MailTransportListener.java:80)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.poll(MailTransportListener.java:61)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(DataInputStream.java:513)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.simpleCommand(Protocol.java:347)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:91)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:201)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:144)
... 11 more
```